# Should I be concerned about messy wiring in breaker box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

We recenently opened our breaker box to add two new circuits to an area we were finishing in our basement. The internal wiring seems haphazard at best and it is rather difficult to see where anything is running at a glance. However my immediate concern was potential heat buildup in the large clump of wires on the right leading to an electrical fire. Some quick googling seems to indicate this might be the case, but I don't have a concrete understanding of where the line is drawn between poor work that is just messy looking and poor work that is dangerous.

Should I be concerned about the current state of this panel?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every hot and neutral wire should be long enough to reach every breaker in the panel.

If you've seen a bunch of "very pretty" panels on Reddit where every wire is nipped off to be as short as possible and still reach the breaker space it's on right now, that is a classic *What Not To Do*.  The main purpose of "purdy panels" like that is for the electrician to take home all that copper - hey, shiny copper is $3/lb at the scrapper!

You also notice in those "purdy panels" they love to bunch up the wires, and some even twist-tie them together.  That's *much worse* thermally - I've even seen one that blatantly violated NEC 310.15(B)(3)(a) in the name of 'purdy'.  These are not competent electricians, they are competent flower arrangers.

This installer smartly left you plenty of length, and did a nice job overshooting and coming back to dispose of extra length.  If you want, you could reroute some wires another way.  And you could probably groom the wires a bit to make them look less chaotic.

Do NOT move breakers. I can tell you don't have enough experience to understand what a MWBC is, or the importance of MWBC phasing, and this panel has a whole bunch of them.  Skilling up on MWBCs and handle-tying those MWBCs is a pre-requisite for what I'll say next, but then you can move breakers around at will to use up some of that length...  e.g. feed top cables into bottom breakers to use up that length, or even go down the opposite gutter, across the bottom and up the other side a little.  Do not cross the bus bar with wires.

For some of the wires I would pull their excess length over so it runs down the left side, doubles back, goes over the main then to their breaker. The lugs on the main breaker are always hot. All busways are hot.

> it is rather difficult to see where anything is running at a glance

**That is NOT the job of the wiring**.  Yes, you have to fiddle and prod to follow wires. That is normal and it is part of the job of working in a panel.  This is a 40/42 space panel, and it's an industrial-quality CH which packs them in 25% tighter than other brands... *so it's gonna be busy in there*. And you have the xFCI breakers sticking out even more into the gutter.

The gutter is designed for that. UL tests these panels fully populated with 120V circuits (pretty much the worst case for wire crowding). UL wouldn't approve the panel if it was a problem.

> between poor work that is just messy looking

Poor work!!??? I assure you, there definitely is something known as "poor work". *That ain't it*, and realize you don't know the difference yet. Don't try to backfill with "snap judgments" based on appearance.  Again, it is NOT the job of electrical installations to visually impress novices.

> Should I be concerned about the current state of this panel?

Yes, but in other areas.

Right off the bat you have MWBCs missing handle-ties, as mentioned. That will bite you if you try to maintain those circuits.

I see 3 empty spaces *in the middle* which suggests to me that breakers were removed. I'm asking myself whether there are actually CHFPCS filler plates on the panel cover, or whether there are just gaping holes there fit for curious fingers to find a bus bar. (and also the steel case, which will put 120V down a finger, and doctors can't fix what that does to a finger).  Since the CHFPCS is fairly flimsy, I prefer to fill empty holes with CH120 breakers.

Lastly I'm wondering if all those red wires indicate the presence of one of those hokey 6/8/10 circuit "transfer switches".  Those things are the mortal enemy of panel neatness, as well as having *serious* problems with MWBCs, GFCI and AFCI. That product type really is a relic of the 1970s.  If generator support is important, get a sliding-plate generator interlock, with a generator breaker in an appropriate location; now *all that wiring* associated with the transfer switch can Simply Go Away.  You will need to move some breakers to place the interlock where it must go, so the MWBC knowledge is a prerequisite, unless you can move only GFCI breakers. (1-pole GFCI breakers cannot be MWBC by definition).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a fill calculation for electric panels like there is for conduit so you're OK. The messy loose wiring is actually preferred because it allows breakers to be moved around in the panel if needed. You don't need to know where the wires go in the panel but do take the time to get an accurate labeling of what each breaker controls. They probably could have done a better job with the white wires from the GF/AF breakers but that's minor.

Comment: Fill rules apply to every passage that building wires enter and exit. Panelboards are no exception. Practically speaking, UL-approved panelboard boxes are so large that nobody will ever come close enough to actually hitting the limit to even worry about doing the calculation, but it certainly is defined, just as much as it is for a single-gang junction box.

Comment: @nobody  I've never seen a cubic inch stamp inside a panel board nor have I seen a chart that gives limits on number on conductors that a certain panel can hold. Yes, you could calculate the cubic inches of a panel and subtract the cubic inches of main breaker and individual breakers. With all due respect, you're getting a little picky with comments.  :-)